# Linux without sysfs/debugfs filesystem

Tags: linux, sysfs

I need to use a system without any sysfs/debugfs (this is a strong requirement, can't change it).

I need to understand how I can manage to set the Linux without this filesystem.

For example when configuring various omap PM (power management features) I need to set the following:

```
echo 1 > /dbg/pm_debug/sleep_while_idle
```

Do you think it is possible to set it as default to 1 for example (I don't need to change the value in runtime) ? How can it be done ?

Comment: Let me put it that way: You are likely going to fail. Reading [Patrick Mochel's paper "The sysfs Filesystem"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf), I honestly doubt that you run a modern Linux system without it.

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for the reply. It's not the first time we are doing it in general, it is a safety issue. anyhow, I found that it is possible to set the default intended value without sysfs. I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the values that are set by sysfs/debugfs are actually set into some variables in kernel, so it is actually an issue of setting specific variables in kernel with predefind (default) value.