# IOCTL call works on some architecture

Tags: c, linux, virtualbox, ioctl

I'm writing a program in C and it needs to look up the IP & MAC address of an interface. I'm using IOCTL calls. Until recently I was still using custom data structure to store theses addresses, and everything was working perfectly.
Then I moved to using standards struct like

`struct in_addr`

`struct ether_addr`.

On my OS (Archlinux), it is still working properly,so that's good. But usually I run my program into a virtualized environment (Slitaz linux) in VirtualBox.I do this so I can run a virtualized network with GNS3. Since these modifications, impossible to get the IOCTL call working properly in Slitaz. When I call

`printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));`

I just get

> No Such Device

If it wasn't working properly on both architecture, I would search more in-depth, but here i'm completely lost, it works fine on Arch but not on Slitaz. it WORKED in Slitaz BEFORE these change, I can still use the older version ( 2 branches in git, one for the old version and one for the current).

Thank you for your help.

Nikko

---

Here are the relevant part of code (I show for MAC oinyl since IP problem is the same):

```
/*
 * Return a ifreq structure for this interface
 * */
    struct ifreq
get_ifreq ( const char * interface )
{

    struct ifreq ifr;
    size_t if_len;


    if_len = strlen(interface);
    if (if_len >= sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)){
        fprintf(stderr,"Interface name too long to open descriptor.\nAbort.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,interface,if_len);

    return ifr;
}

int 
get_mac_address(const char * interface, struct ether_addr * ether) {
    int fd ;
    struct ifreq ifr = get_ifreq(interface);
    if((fd = get_socketudp()) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to get mac address.\n");
        return -1;
    };

    if(ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFHWADDR,&ifr) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",strerror(fd));
        fprintf(stderr,"Error while operating IOCTL (MAC resolving).\n");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    } 
    close(fd);
    memcpy(ether,&ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data,ETH_ALEN);
    return 0;

}
```

And in the main.c, where I call this function :

```
char * interface = NULL;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------
*  Our OWN mac address & ip address
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
struct ether_addr mac;
struct in_addr ip;

    int
main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char * operation = NULL;
    char * hostA = NULL;
    char * hostB = NULL;
    int c = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((c = getopt(argc,argv,"m:i:a:b:f:l:")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case 'm':
                operation = optarg;
                if (strncmp(operation,"mitm",4) != 0 &&
                        strncmp(operation,"flood",5) != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Operation %s is unknown.Abort\n",operation);
                    abort();
                }
                break;
            case 'i':
                interface = optarg;
                break;

            case '?':
                fprintf(stderr,"Option %c requires an argument",optopt);
                abort();
        }
    }


    /* Check options consistency */
    if(operation == NULL) { 
        fprintf(stderr,"No Operations given. Abort.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (interface == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"No interface given. Abort.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 



    /* Store our own mac address */
    if (get_mac_address(interface,mac) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Abort.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the anser I changed my get_ifreq method to :

```
    struct ifreq
get_ifreq ( const char * interface )
{

    struct ifreq ifr;
    size_t if_len;

    memset(ifr.ifr_name,0x00,IFNAMSIZ);
    if_len = strlen(interface);
    if (if_len >= IFNAMSIZ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Interface name too long to open descriptor.\nAbort.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,interface,if_len);

    return ifr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply reading `/sys/class/net/eth0/address` file?

Comment: I want the code to be as much portable as possible. Not relying on specific folders.

Comment: `/sys` is a mountpoint to `sysfs` filesystem which exports data directly from kernel. It should be available on any linux 2.6 system (except for very exotic cases like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913935/linux-without-sysfs-debugfs-filesystem )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that there is additional garbage in the ifreq structure that you're not clearing out here:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
if_len = strlen(interface);
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,interface,if_len);
```

You declare the struct ifreq on the stack but don't initialize it so the bytes in that structure are potentially random garbage. You then copy exactly if_len bytes into it, but what about the bytes immediately following that. Assuming if_len is less than IFNAMSIZ, how will the kernel know to stop at if_len in interpreting the interface name?

I would clear the structure prior to the strncpy.

Comment: Wow thanks, it has worked ! How come it worked before with the same interface name ... I dunno. But Thanks !!